# How add a swift package to a Multiplatform App on Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode12, swift-package-manager

is it possible to add Swift Package to both targets of a Multiplatform app?
I'm using the steps below and the package can either be added to iOS or macOS but not both.

**Steps:**

Open Xcode 12 or newer and hit ⌘⇧N to create a new project. Navigate to the new “Multiplatform” section, select App, and press Next. Then save your project as usual.

[image: Multiplatform App]

Try to add a [swift package](https://github.com/byaruhaf/package-name) to this app, you will need to select Target either iOS or macOS but not both. The Target selected will be the only one able to access the swift package.

[image: Add Swift Package]

Trying to add the swift package again to another target results in the error below.

[image: The project already contains the swift package]